# Convert CompletableFuture to Coroutine

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am a newbie in Kotlin world and would like to know, if it is possible to convert `CompletableFuture` to `Coroutine` or how to use togheter.

Why I would like to do that, because all methods of [AsyncCrudRepository](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/api/io/micronaut/data/repository/async/AsyncCrudRepository.html) returns `CompletableFuture`.

Comment: You can [await()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8/kotlinx.coroutines.future/java.util.concurrent.-completion-stage/await.html) on CompletableFuture from inside a coroutine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use the following: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8

Maven/Gradle: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8

It is the official jdk8 integration by the kotlin team. Well maintained, and contains examples and documentation on how to use with `CompletableFuture`

### Since `kotlinx-coroutines` version `1.7.0`

`kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8` has been merged with `kotlinx-coroutines-core`

Now the only dependency needed is `kotlinx-coroutines-core`: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core

Main repository for kotlin coroutines: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like the repo got moved. Is there an updated link to these docs?

Comment: @frodo2975 updated my answer. since 1.7.0 you can use `kotlinx-coroutines-core` without the extra library to get jdk8 coroutines extensions

Comment: I could not get this working with just the kotlinx-coroutines-core package I had to import org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8

Comment: @RyanHendry note not to confuse kotlin and kotlinx-coroutines version. the change is since kotlinx-coroutines 1.7.0

Comment: @Tom Thanks, had some gradle issues and it was pulling in an older version. I set kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm to 1.7.2 as well as kotlinx-coroutines-core and it worked

Answer (score 2):

The modern way to do this is to add `kotlinx-coroutines-core`:
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master#gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.1")
}
```

Then, you can call `.await()` on a `CompletableFuture` like

```kotlin
suspend fun getResult() {
    val result = client
        // returns CompletableFuture
        .doTask()
        .await()
}
```